# SQL: selecting fields from another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am new to sql and I appreciate help with the following:
I have 2 tables: table1 contains userID and field y1 while table 2  contains userID and three additional fields: x1, x2, x3 and x4
For each row in table1 I need to select x4 from table 2 if x1, x2 and x3 are not null.
UserID can appear more than once in table1 or table2 and the important thing is that I need the result column rows to be as in table1.
Thanks

Here is an example:

Table 1:

```
UserID y1
1            long
2            short
```

Table 2:

```
UserID x1 x2 x3 x4
1            blue round big 11
1            blue square big 22
2            blue round   big 33
3            red square  small 77
```

Result for x1=blue, x2=round and x3=big

```
UserID  x4
1            11
2            33
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  Clarification is also helpful.  What is this supposed to mean:  "I need the result column rows to be as in table1"?

Comment: Just added an example to my question Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely suer what you mean by the last line, but I assume you want all rows from table1 with the addition of table2.x4.

You're query would be something like this:
SELECT table1.*, table2.x4 from table1 LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 ON table1.UserID = table2.UserID AND NOT (table2.x1 IS NULL) AND NOT (table2.x2 IS NULL) NOT (table2.x3 IS NULL)

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want:

```
select t1.*, t2.x4
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on t1.userid = t2.userid
where t2.x1 = 'blue' and t2.x2 = 'round' and t2.x3 = 'big';
```